# TypeError: string indices must be integers - python json to csv convertion

Tags: python, json, csv

I got an error with my script, can someone help me to resolve this issue and let me know what I need to change or modify with my script.

Error is ***TypeError: string indices must be integers***

```
import json
import csv

with open("/home/admin/myfile.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

    fname = "myprodtest.csv"

with open(fname, "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    csv_file.writerow(["PROD1","PROD2","PROD3","PROD4","PROD5"])
    for item in data["result"]:
        csv_file.writerow([item['PROD1'],item['PROD2'],item['PROD3'],item['PROD4'],item['PROD5']])
        print (data)
```

Comment: I'm guessing `item` is a list and not a `dict`?

Comment: Hi @Guy, yes its list.

Comment: Either data resolving to a string/list or one/all of data['results'] are. Would need error trace or file content to tell more

Comment: Than you need to access the items with an int, not a string.